# Jslink "undefined" object

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, jslink

Usually `undefined` means I forgot to add a field to a view (!), but in this case I'm using a `dataview` and the field is definitely there.

The key line - the undefined field is `Image_x0020_upload`:

```
var ret = "<div class='slide'><a href='xxxx/Post.aspx?ID=" + ctx.CurrentItem.ID + "'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Image_x0020_upload + "<br /><h5>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + "</h5></a></div>";
return ret;
```

This works within the native site but when I add the dataview webpart linked to this list to the parent site, the image field is `undefined` while the other fields display correctly.

Comment: As a starting point investigate what fields are actually available by doing `console.log(ctx.CurrentItem)` and use your browser's developer tools to drill down through it. It might give you some clues.

Comment: The field is present  - and now it "started" working in IE and Chrome but not in Firefox. Which is weird ...

Comment: The plot thickens - when I move everything over to a production page (in same library as test page), the image field shows in edit mode but not when I save the page. So the script runs, other fields show just not the image upload field.

Comment: Hmmm - when I checked the page in, the image field appeared. Another appalling Msft design. Still no luck in Firefox.